# Why are my dns options specified in /etc/network/interfaces not parsed by resolvconf?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, resolv.conf

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server which has two IP addresses specified on a single interface. They are defined in /etc/network/interfaces like so:

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11

iface em1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

As per [the debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface) I have specified multiple IP addresses in the modern style by simply declaring multiple iface stanzas referring to the same interface.

However, when the networking on this server comes up, /etc/resolv.conf is empty but for the standard header:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

And all DNS lookups are therefore failing as it does not try to contact the nameservers.

I've clearly specified the local nameservers to use in the `dns-nameservers` line in /etc/network/interfaces above. Why are they not in resolv.conf?

<sub>Actual IP addresses have been changed to protect the innocent</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that what seems to be happening is that when resolvconf parses the interfaces file, because I have multiple iface stanzas that target the same interface, the specified dns options in the first stanza are discarded when resolvconf then parses the second iface stanza.

If I rewrite my /etc/network/interfaces to look like this:

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1

iface em1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11
```

Then resolv.conf gets generated with the content I expect:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.10
nameserver 192.168.1.11
```